# No match for 'operator* in '(1.0e + 0 - ((double)u)) * bezPoints[i][(j + 1)]'

Tags: c++, qt, bezier

I am getting this error in trying to implement the Bezier Curve psuedocode in C++ in Qt , have the method implementation below.

```
    void GLWidget::drawBezierCurve() {
            int N_PTS = vertices.size();
            Point bezPoints[N_PTS][N_PTS];

            for (float u = 0.0; u <= 1.0; u += 0.01){
                for(int diag = N_PTS/2; diag >= 0;diag--){
                    for(int i = 0; i <= diag; i++){
                        int j = diag - i;
                        bezPoints[i][j] = (1.0 - u) * bezPoints[i][j+1] + u * bezPoints[i+1][j];
                    }
                }
                theImage.setPixel(bezPoints[0][0], bezPoints[0][0], RGBValue(100,12,140), 255);
            }
}
```

Comment: which Point class do you use?.Obviously it doesnt define an operator *(float)

Comment: Since you are using Qt, you can use [`QPoint`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpoint.html) if you want.

Comment: Since we don't know what `Point` is, we can only guess. Maybe it's a typedef for `basic_point<float>` and there is a function template `template<class T> basic_point<T> operator*(T scale, basic_point<T> vec)` -- in which case you should change `(1.0-u)` to `(1.0f-u)` to make template argument deduction work. But maybe there just isn't any `operator*` that takes a `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is because you are multiplying a float by a Point object. You are most likely going to need to define you're own multiplication method for this operation, or overload the * operator to perform this, depending on which fields in the Point object you intend to multiply the floating point number by.

Something like:

```
float operator* (const float num, const Point& point) {
    return num * point.floating_point_field;
}
```

Where the floating_point_field is the member of the class that you want to multiply and it should also be of the same type as float, otherwise you'll have to start doing something more involved to define the multiplication.

Alternatively, if the multiplication is as simple as in the example above you could just use a getter in the code such as:

```
u * bezPoints[i][j+1].get_floating_point_value()
```

Hope that helps,

Matt

Comment: Multiplying a scalar (float) value by a vector (Point) value should return another vector value, not a scalar.